# How do we create a recursive function to find the highest digit of a number?

Tags: c

The number is integer,but i don't know exactly which condition is the most appropriate to use so that the loop will end.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt and show it to us, describing your problems with it.

Comment: https://ideone.com/G4BTgv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to check if the passed integer is zero like here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int largest(int val, int lrg)
{
    int newlargest = abs(val % 10) > lrg ? abs(val % 10): lrg;
    val /= 10;
    if(val) newlargest = largest(val, newlargest);
    return newlargest;
}

int main()
{
    int num = -38543045;
    printf("%d - largest = %d\n", num, largest(num,0));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/asUUGV